# Error while cloning GitHub COSMOS Repository. (GO)

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, cosmos-sdk

i want to clone and install a GitHub repository but get an error.

git clone https://github.com/bandprotocol/chain

cd chain && git checkout v2.3.0

make install

Result:
..\go\pkg\mod\github.com\rcrowley\go-metrics@v0.0.0-20200313005456-10cdbea86bc0\runtime.go:5:2: found packages pprof (elf.go) and proto (proto.go) in C:\Users\user\go\GO Language\src\runtime\pprof

make: *** [Makefile:24: install] Error 1

If i delete for example one file he takes the next two out of this folder.

Thanks for help and answers

Comment: Can you tell how you are trying to install? This is not reproducible as is.

Comment: Please edit your post, add all the commands iimplicitely, so we can be sure what repository you are talking about.

Comment: Added it to my post.

Comment: First problem I think, when you do `make install` you still have not build anything. Before `make install`, try `make`. `make` command must succeed before you try to install what you built.

Comment: I runned "make" and still get the same errors.